# Inequality related to simplex projection

Tags: inequality, optimization

I came across this while trying to work out the expression for the projection of a point on the unit simplex.

Consider real numbers $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \dots \geq x_n$.

For $1 \leq m \leq n $ define $$\bar{x}_m = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m x_i. $$ Let $$k = \max \{ 1 \leq i \leq n : \frac{1}{i} + x_i - \bar{x}_i \geq 0 \}.$$

Note $\frac{1}{i} + x_i - \bar{x}_i$ equals 1 for $i=1$ so $k$ is well defined.

Clearly $x_j \leq \bar{x}_j - \frac{1}{j}$ for all $j \geq k+1$.

But do we have the stronger inequality  for $j \geq k+1$:
$$ x_j \leq \bar{x}_k  -\frac{1}{k} ?$$

If not, is there a simple counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to prove that $\displaystyle x_{k+1} \leq \bar{x}_k - \frac{1}{k}$ as $\displaystyle x_{k+1} \geq x_{k+2} \geq \dots \geq x_{n}$.

We have from the definition of $k$ that $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{k+1} + x_{k+1} - \bar{x}_{k+1} \leq 0$$ so
$$ (k+1) \bar{x}_{k+1} - (k+1)x_{k+1} \geq 1$$
i.e.,
$$ (x_1 + \dots + x_{k+1} ) - (k+1)x_{k+1} \geq 1 $$
so,
$$ (x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k) - k x_{k+1} \geq 1$$
or,
$$ x_{k+1} \leq \bar{x}_k - \frac{1}{k}$$